# Prove polynomial transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, transformation

Suppose a polynomial transformation:

[image]

How do I prove the "closed under addition" property of linearity? I am trying this:

[image]

I try to expand the equation on the left hand side, but I don't get anything resembling the right hand side. Thoughts?

By the way, is this how I would prove any polynomial transformation is linear - by picking two arbitrary polynomials with unknown coefficients and manipulating them?

Comment: (i) The mapping $T$ does not map $P_2$ to $P_2$, it is to $P_4$. (ii) The equation you wrote can be easily verified to be correct, so that part of the job is almost finished.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. x^2 can be multiplied to each term and factored out to form the right hand side of the equation. Also, thanks for the correction!

Comment: Or you can use $x^2(A+B)=x^2A+x^2B$ to save doing the expansions.

Comment: OK. In general, if I am faced with a polynomial transformation, and I am told to prove linearity, the best approach is to use two arbitrary polynomials in P_{2} and then manipulate them, correct?

Comment: That's one way. Sometimes there are shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $p,q$ two polynomials. Then $p+q$ is a polynomial defined as $(p+q)(x)=p(x)+q(x)$

$$
T(p+q)(x) = x^2(p+q)(x) = x^2 p(x) + x^2 q(x) = T(p)(x) + T(q)(x),
$$

or,

$$
T(p+q) = T(p) + T(q).
$$

In a similar fashion you have show the following; take $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$
T(\alpha p)(x) = x^2\cdot (\alpha p)(x) = \alpha x^2 p(x) = \alpha T(p)(x),
$$

or $T(\alpha p)=\alpha T(p)$. We conclude that $T$ is a linear operator.

Answer (score 0):

Every polynomial of degree 2 is identified with an element of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ namely (a.b.c). The same applies to polynomials of any degree. Every polynomial of degree n is identified with an element of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. So your mapping is $T(a,b,c)=(a,b,c,0,0)$ where $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to \mathbb{R}^{5}$. Therefore your mapping is obviously linear because it represents a 5x3 matrix.!!